# Non-split exact sequence of modules

Tags: modules, examples-counterexamples, exact-sequence

> Find a module $M$ and a submodule $N$ such that $|M| = 100$, $|N| = 20$, $M$ is not cyclic, and the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow M/N \rightarrow 0$ does not split.

I have tried $M = Z/2 \oplus Z/2 \oplus Z/5 \oplus Z/5$ and $N = Z/2 \oplus Z/2 \oplus Z/5$, but I don't know how to interpret $M/N$, let alone prove/disprove $M \cong M/N \oplus N$ (so that the sequence doesn't split).

Any help? (explanation would be much appreciated)

Comment: What ground ring?

Comment: Try putting a $Z/25$ in $M$.

Comment: @Randall whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

We'll work with $\mathbb Z$-modules, i.e., abelian groups.  Note $|M/N| = |M|/|N| = 5$ so $M/N$ is going to be cyclic of order $5$.  Thus we can guarentee that the sequence does not split if $\mathbb Z/5$ is not a direct summand of $M$.

One group that has $\mathbb Z/5$ as a quotient but **not** as a summand is $\mathbb Z/25$ so this is a good candidate to build $M$ from.  To get the right order lets choose $M = \mathbb Z/4 \oplus \mathbb Z/25$.  A subgroup of order $20$ inside $M$ is $N = \mathbb Z/4 \oplus 5\mathbb Z/25$.  We know just by order that $M/N \simeq \mathbb Z/5$ and we have chosen $M$ so that this isn't a summand.  So our SES won't split.

If you want an explicit proof that it doesn't split note that $M/N$ is generated by $(0, 1) + N \in M/N$ so if there's a splitting then it comes from a homomorphism $\phi\colon\mathbb Z/5 \to \mathbb Z/4\oplus\mathbb Z/25$ satisfying $\phi(1) = (a, 1 + 5b)$ where $a \in \mathbb Z/4$ and $b \in \mathbb Z/25$.  This means $\phi(0) = 5\phi(1)$ better equal $(0, 0)$ if such a homomorphism is possible.  Show that $5\phi(1) \neq (0, 0)$.